# Python: Separating txt file to multiple files using a reoccuring symbol

Tags: python, split, txt

I have a .txt file of amino acids separated by ">node" like this:

Filename.txt :

> >NODE_1
> MSETLVLTRPDDWHVHLRDGAALQSVVPYTARQFARAIAMPNLKPPITTAEQAQAYRERI
> KFFLGTDSAPHASVMKENSVCGAGCFTALSALELYAEAFEAAGALDKLEAFASFHGADFY
> GLPRNTTQVTLRKTEWTLPESVPFGEAAQLKPLRGGEALRWKLD*
> >NODE_2
> MSTWHKVQGRPKAQARRPGRKSKDDFVTRVEHDAKNDALLQLVRAEWAMLRSDIATFRGD
> MVERFGKVEGEITGIKGQIDGLKGEMQGVKGEVEGLRGSLTTTQWVVGTAMALLAVVTQV
> PSIISAYRFPPAGSSAFPAPGSLPTVPGSPASAASAP*

I want to separate this file into two (or as many as there are nodes) files;

Filename1.txt :

> >NODE
> MSETLVLTRPDDWHVHLRDGAALQSVVPYTARQFARAIAMPNLKPPITTAEQAQAYRERI
> KFFLGTDSAPHASVMKENSVCGAGCFTALSALELYAEAFEAAGALDKLEAFASFHGADFY
> GLPRNTTQVTLRKTEWTLPESVPFGEAAQLKPLRGGEALRWKLD*

Filename2.txt :

> >NODE
> MSTWHKVQGRPKAQARRPGRKSKDDFVTRVEHDAKNDALLQLVRAEWAMLRSDIATFRGD
> MVERFGKVEGEITGIKGQIDGLKGEMQGVKGEVEGLRGSLTTTQWVVGTAMALLAVVTQV
> PSIISAYRFPPAGSSAFPAPGSLPTVPGSPASAASAP*

With a number after the filename

This code works, however it deletes the ">NODE" line and does not create a file for the last node (the one without a '>' afterwards).

```
with open('FilePathway') as fo:
    op = ''
    start = 0
    cntr = 1
    for x in fo.read().split("\n"):
        if x.startswith('>'):
            if start == 1:
                with open (str(cntr) + '.fasta','w') as opf:
                    opf.write(op)
                    opf.close()
                    op = ''
                    cntr += 1
            else:
                    start = 1
        else:
            if op == '':
                op = x
            else:
                op = op + '\n' + x
    fo.close()
```

I can´t seem to find the mistake. Would be thankful if you could point it out to me.

Thank you for your help!

---

Hi again! Thank you for all the comments. With your help, I managed to get it to work perfectly. For anyone with similar problems, this is my final code:

```
import os
import glob

folder_path = 'FilePathway'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.fasta')):
  with open(filename) as fo:
      for line in fo.readlines():
        if line.startswith('>'):
            original = line
            
content = [original]
fileno = 1
filename = filename
y = filename.replace(".fasta","_")

def writefasta():
    global content, fileno
    if len(content) > 1:
        with open(f'{y}{fileno}.fasta', 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(''.join(content))
        content = [line]
        fileno += 1


with open('FilePathway') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('>NODE'):
            writefasta()
        else:
            content.append(line)
    writefasta()
```

Comment: Why not use a string.split(" NODE") for example, while inserting NODE back in every other item in the list? You can probably even use list comprehension to do so in one line.

Comment: the example you gave and the explanation are not match. you say separated by ">node", however it is actually only "NODE" in the example?

Comment: In your example, we see three lines after ">NODE". Are there actually 3 lines or is it just one long line? Could there be more or less than 3 lines? Also, as you're using a work manager for the file open, you don't need the explicit close

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake the node was all capital letters, and the amino acids are in several lines and usually differ in line number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
def writefasta(d):
    if len(d['content']) > 1:
        with open(f'Filename{d["fileno"]}.fasta', 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(''.join(d['content']))
        d['content'] = ['>NODE\n']
        d['fileno'] += 1


with open('test.fasta') as fin:
    D = {'content': ['>NODE\n'], 'fileno': 1}
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('>NODE'):
            writefasta(D)
        else:
            D['content'].append(line)
    writefasta(D)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be better way. It is going to write only on odd iterations. So that, ">NODE" will be skipped and files will be created only for the real content.

```
 with open('filename.txt') as fo:
        cntr=1
        for i,content in enumerate(fo.read().split("\n")):
            if i%2 == 1:
                with open (str(cntr) + '.txt','w') as opf:
                    opf.write(content)
                    cntr += 1
```

By the way, since you are using **context manager**, you dont need to close the file.

> Context managers allow you to allocate and release resources precisely
> when you want to. It opens the file, writes some data to it and then
> closes it.

Please check: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html

Comment: You presuppose that the characters between >NODE_1 and >NODE_2 is just one line. Is that the case? Also, there won't be a newline character in the output file which could be important (depending on how it gets read).

Comment: Yes, that s true. Actually, the question needs to be explained a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

```
    with open('FileName') as fo:
        cntr = 1
        for line in fo.readlines():
            with open (f'{str(cntr)}.fasta','w') as opf:
               opf.write(line)
               opf.close()
               op = ''
               cntr += 1
        fo.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? You'll get a new file for every line in the input file. *op* is never used. *fo* and *opf* have unnecessary explicit closes.